# Scroll the screen, not the cursor, when using scrollwheel

Tags: mouse, scrolling, x11, terminal

I'm using Vim in a terminal, so scrolling with the scroll wheel uses the `\e[A` and `\e[B` syntax (where `\e` symbolizes `\x1b`, or escape).

However, Vim interprets this by moving the cursor up or down a line. The desired behavior is that the *screen* is moved up or down, like `<C-e>` and `<C-y>` do.

How can I tell Vim to move the screen when I used my scroll wheel, while keeping the cursor on the same line? This should work in all common modes (insert, normal, visual select).

I've already tried, for example, `:nnoremap <esc>[A <C-e>` (replacing `<esc>` with a literal escape character inserted with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>), but this proved to be futile.

I'm using Vim 7.4.52 on Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME.

Comment: Could you limit the question to an operating system or windowing environment?

Comment: @200_success Alright, I've edited my environment into the question.

Comment: I think this question should be tagged 'terminal' too.  Is it un-editable because it's answered?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Doorknob said in his comment, `:set mouse=a` fixes the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to do this *without* setting `mouse=a`? I don't want accidental clicks messing up my editing flow.

Comment: the `a` in `mouse=a` stands for `all` (not append). from `:help mouse` : _"the mouse can be enabled for different modes ... Normally you would enable the mouse in all four modes with: :set mouse=a"_ at least in my vim when I enabled that it didn't mess up with mode switching (just enabled scrolling - and "click to go to the line")

Comment: Though this thread is old, for someone who wants `set mouse=a` without accidental clicks messing up flow, `:map <LeftMouse> <nop>` would do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a few years late, but you can use
`nmap <Down> <C-e>`
`nmap <Up> <C-y>`

This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you want is what happens on my vim.  I can't find a setting that turns it on/off.  Maybe check the [:help scrolling](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-mouse-wheel)?  [`scrolloff`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrolloff') might be involved.

You could also consider using [marks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions) as a workaround.

1. <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (set mark 'a')
2. scroll the screen as you'd like
3. <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (send cursor to mark 'a')

Comment: I get this behavior even without loading my vimrc (`vim -u NONE`). This is Vim 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME.

Comment: @Doorknob
And I get the window instead of the cursor moving without my `.vimrc` (just `set mouse=a`).

`:help scrolling` says that the scrolling behavior is platform specific.  I'm using vim in iterm2 on OSX.

Comment: Aha! `:set mouse=a` has fixed the problem for me. Edit that into your answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks!